# Update multiple ObservableCollection objects parallely and notify to caller/UI

Tags: .net, wpf, task-parallel-library, system.reactive, async-await

I have a method calling an UpdateCollections method which currently updates 3 `ObservableCollection<T>` objects *sequantially* at present. To improve performance and update time delay for these 3 collections, I would like to do it in separate threads or whatsoever, and notify the caller and UI when any of the 3 collection update completes and also be able to **preserve cross thread updates** because all 3 collection objects are parts of same main collection object.

Below is the sample code that runs sequentially as of now:

```
public class CustomObservableCollection
{
    public ObservableCollection<T> CollectionObject1;
    public ObservableCollection<T> CollectionObject2;
    public ObservableCollection<T> CollectionObject3;

    public void UpdateCollectionX...N(CustomObservableCollection objectWithOnlyUpdates)
    {.............}
}

public class SomeBusinessClass
{
    CustomObservableCollection mainCollectionObject;
    public void UpdateCollections(CustomObservableCollection objectWithUpdatesOnly)
    {
        mainCollectionObject.UpdateCollection1(objectWithUpdatesOnly);
        mainCollectionObject.UpdateCollection2(objectWithUpdatesOnly);
        mainCollectionObject.UpdateCollection3(objectWithUpdatesOnly);
    }
}
```

Basically, by observing above code, I want to call the **`UpdateCollectionX`** methods in **parallel or separate threads**, so I found **some choices as below**. What could be the *best way* to achieve this, and also how should I convert my current code so that as soon as 1 of the collection update method completes, it sends some kind of notification to the calling method and/or possibly UI (to update itself as its a **`WPF`** app):

1. Task Parallel Library
2. Reactive Extensions (may be by implementing `IObservable` for the class `CustomObservableCollection`
3. async/await
4. `Thread` class

> I can use any method from above or some other better method but am most
>   worried about cross thread exceptions that may come while updating in
>   parallel, as all 3 collection objects are part of same custom
>   collection object.

Comment: Inserting something in a collection takes essentially no time. Why do you want to do this in parallel? What is UpdateCollectionX doing that you want it to run in parallel?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos UpdateCollectionX method updates the objects to insert new object/update properties of existing objects and remove deleted objects from the respective collections and it does take time, moreover if say UpdateCollection1() method takes 1 second while UpdateCollection2 or 3 takes 10 seconds the UI is blocked until all three UpdateCollectionX() methods finish. Each collection object is bound to separate grid but if 1 grid is updating every other also waits it to finish. I hope I am clear now.. I might update my question later..